# qq-plot ignoring a row in R

Tags: r, plot

So my task is to compare te BMI of students from a survey to the average BMI in germany, for men and woman seperatly. I got the woman, now I need to do the men. But there is one row I am supposed to ignore:

[image]

```
#men: normal distribution?
qqnorm(mBMI$BMI)
qqline(mBMI$BMI)
#we can exclude the third line
qqnorm(mBMI[-3]$BMI)
qqline(mBMI[-3]$BMI)
```

But the (`mBMI[-3]$BMI`) does nothing, the plot looks exactly the same and after that I want to do a shapiro test that also ignores the third row, but it doesn't and I get the wrong result.

Comment: try the other way: `mBMI$BMI[-3]`

Comment: YES that was it :D omg thank you, they wrote it wrong in the lecture notes. I thought I was going insane.

Comment: Good luck with your exam :)